# Splitt several JSON Strings in a single Line

Tags: java, json, filereader

I have a txt-file which is a single line with several JSON Strings. My problem is that i don't know how to get every JSON Object.

```
try {
       FileReader fr = new FileReader("SelectedChoice.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

       String zeile ="";

       while((zeile = br.readLine())!=null) {
           System.out.println(zeile);
           JSONObject choice = new JSONObject(zeile);
           System.out.println(choice);
       }

       br.close();
       fr.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

This is the String which have to converted:

```
{"Item":"MasterNode","Choice 1":1,"Choice 2":0,"Choice 3":-1}{"Item":"WorkerNode","Choice 1":1,"Choice 2":0,"Choice 3":-1}
```

This code only converts the first JSON String in the line, whilst I want to convert all of them.

Comment: Is there a newline character behind the second line of JSON?

Comment: Sorry, it is actually one big line. I have edited my post.

Comment: It's not actually valid JSON like you posted it now. I can imagine that therefore you are having problems. Either put each object on a separate line or else put your objects in an array and make sure the JSON is valid. You can test whether the JSON is valid here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I pulled it up in my IDE and downloaded the `org.json` library and it ran just fine. Because of the way you read the file, it may be that you are loosing one line and just keeping the last line. If you want to save the `JSONObject`, You could always try saving the `JSONObject` in an `ArrayList` or some other collection such as this...

```
Collection<JSONObject> JSONObjects = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("SelectedChoice.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String zeile ="";

    while((zeile = br.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(zeile);
        JSONObject choice = new JSONObject(zeile);
        System.out.println(choice);
        JSONObjects.add(choice);
    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could than access the Collection after your file is finished being read.

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

*P.S.* If you have any other questions feel free to ask!

> #### Edit
>
> So I just read in the comments above that you thought it should be one line. If >you want the too groups to be separate, you might want to put the new line >back. If you want that to be one `JSONObject`, you might be running into a >syntax error. Try adding a `,` in between the two groups of values.